# Linear fit without slope in r

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I want to fit a linear model with no slope and extract information of it. My objective is to know which is the best y-intercept for an horizontal line in a data set and also evaluate [image: R2] from derived linear fit to identify if *y* has a particular behavior (*x* is date). I've using `range` to evaluate behavior, but I'm looking for an index without unit.

Removing y-intercept:

```
X <- 1:10

Y <- 2:11

lm1 <- lm(Y~X + 0, data = data.frame(X=X,Y=Y)) # y-intercept remove opt 1

lm1 <- lm(Y~X - 1, data = data.frame(X=X,Y=Y)) # y-intercept remove opt 2

lm1 <- lm(Y~0 + X, data = data.frame(X=X,Y=Y)) # y-intercept remove opt 3

lm1$coefficients
       X 
1.142857 

summary(lm1)$r.squared    
[1] 0.9957567
```

All the `lm` showed before, has [image: R2]. But, if I evaluate:

```
lm2 <- lm(Y~1, data = data.frame(X=X,Y=Y))

lm2$coefficients
(Intercept) 
        6.5 

summary(lm2)$r.squared
[1] 0
```

There is a way to calculate [image: R2] out of `lm` function or calculate an index to identify how much *y* is represented by an horizontal line?

Comment: The y intercept with no slope is an lm model is equal to the mean of the DV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `lmObject` be your linear model returned by `lm` (called with `y = TRUE` to return `y`).

- If your model has intercept, then R-squared is computed as

  ```
  with(lmObject, 1 - c(crossprod(residuals) / crossprod(y - mean(y))) )
  ```
- If your model does not have an intercept, then R-squared is computed as

  ```
  with(lmObject, 1 - c(crossprod(residuals) / crossprod(y)) )
  ```

Note, if your model is only an intercept (so it is certainly from the 1st case above), you have

```
residuals = y - mean(y)
```

thus R-squared is always `1 - 1 = 0`.

In regression analysis, it is always recommended to include intercept in the model to get unbiased estimate. A model with intercept only is the NULL model. Any other model is compared with this NULL model for further analysis of variance.

---

A note. The value / quantity you want has nothing to do with regression. You can simply compute it as

```
c(crossprod(Y - mean(Y)) / crossprod(Y))  ## `Y` is your data
#[1] 0.1633663
```

Alternatively, use

```
(length(Y) - 1) * var(Y) / c(crossprod(Y))
#[1] 0.1633663
```

Comment: Thanks you! A great answer, I tried your note's code and works as I've looking for.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone avoid the confusion I got into, `crossprod` here (as in `crossprod(residuals)`, `crossprod(y)` etc) will return the sum of squares..